# Cannot create TFS query folder

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2010

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475889%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#create), there is supposed to be a **New Folder** item on the context menu for both **My Queries** and **Team Queries**. Yet, when I right click on either of these, I do not have the option to create a new folder. The only options I have are:

- New Query
- New Work Items with Microsoft Excel
- Copy
- Paste
- Add to My Favorites

What am I missing? Why is the **New Folder** option not available? Is there something else I need to configure before I will get the option? I've already verified that I am a member of the Project Administrators group, and I don't have any issues creating new queries.

Comment: Do you have permission to create folders? Is this in the Web Access or VS? If VS, what version?

Comment: @DaveShaw, VS 2010 SP1, and yes, I'm a member of Project Administrators group.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct permissions? According to MSDN

`To create or copy a query folder, your Read permission must be set for the query or folder that you want to copy, and your Contribute permission must be set for the destination query folder.`